# How to make assignments to empty cells in data.table in nested loop?

Tags: r, loops, nested, data.table, variable-assignment

I        am trying to make assignments to empty cells in a data.table in a nested loop.

I have created a data.table of dimensions 15x15. It is empty except for column names. I would like to loop through each cell in the table, perform and an operation on a separate dataset and assign the output of that operation to the empty cell. However, so far I can’t even manage to loop through a data.table and make assignments.

So far I have tried

```
For (I in 1:15)
For (j in 1:15) {
[ dataframe[ I, j  :=. 100 ]
```

But when this runs it only populates a single column at the end.

I have also tried with

```
[ dataframe[i, ..j := 100]
And [ dataframe[i, ... M = false := 100] or whatever it is
```

Nothing seems to work

I know the problem is with the data.table assignment statement I just don’t know how to fix it.

Basically I am trying to populate a polychoric correlation plot.

Comment: can you privide a smaller sample size, like 3x3 data.table, and provide the desired output for this 3x3 data.table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution below.
Note that the `data.table` needs to be initialized with the expected rows / columns before trying to make assignement on `dt[i,j]`

```r
library(data.table)

n <- 5

dt <- data.table(matrix(0,n,n))

for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {dt[i, (j):=i*j]}
}
dt[]
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#> 1:  1  2  3  4  5
#> 2:  2  4  6  8 10
#> 3:  3  6  9 12 15
#> 4:  4  8 12 16 20
#> 5:  5 10 15 20 25
```